# Call aspx method in ascx user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have two aspx pages : A.aspx and B.aspx.
This pages haved one method Calculate().

Each pages include user control C.ascx.

How I can call method Calculate in C.ascx?

I find one way, but this very dirty:

```
A pageA = this.Page as A;

if (page == null) {
    B pageB = this.Page as B;
    pageB.Calculate();
}
else {
    pageA.Calculate();
}
```

How I can improve this code?

I have 2 blocks in each page. I check condition in usercontrol and if condition true, I want hide usercontrol in page and show another div. Maybe I can rewrite code in another ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looks like your design is wrong in that case and you should have `Calculate()` method inside of your user control and not in your page. You should actually be using the user control in your container page.

Another way, is to refactor that method to a separate class and thus you can re-use that in your user control and in your page.

Comment: I have 2 blocks in each page. I check condition in usercontrol and if condition true, I want hide usercontrol in page and show another div. Do I can make this with help other class?

Comment: @prog7778 yes you can ... give a try

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This answer help find a another way. I create interface which constaint calculate method and realize him in each class.